# Classify every instance of a RDD | Apache Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm starting to work with RDD's and I have some doubts. In my case, I have a RDD and I want to classify his data. My RDD contains the following:

```
Array[(String, String)] = Array((data: BD=bd_users,BD_classified,contains_people, rbd: BD=bd_users,BD_classified,contains_people),
(data: BD=bd_users,BD_classified,contains_people,contains_users, user: id=8282bd, BD_USERS,bdd),
(data: BD=bd_experts,BD_exp,contains_exp,contains_adm, rbd: BD=bd_experts,BD_ea,contains_exp,contains_adm),
(data: BD=bd_test,BD_test,contains_acc,contains_tst, rbd: BD=bd_test,BD_test,contains_tst,contains_t))
```

As you can see the RDD contains two strings, the first one start with data and the second one starts with rbd. What I want to do is classify every instance of this RDD as you can see here:

```
If the instance contains bd_users & BD_classified -> users
bd_experts & BD_exp -> experts
BD_test -> tests
```

The **output** would be something like this for this RDD:

```
1. Users
2. Users
3. Experts
4. Test
```

To do this I would like to use a map that calls a function for every instance in this RDD but I don't know how can orientate this:

```
val rdd_groups = rdd_1.map(x=>x(0).toString).map(x => getGroups(x))
def getGroups(input: String): (String) = {
//here i should use for example case to classify this strings?
}
```

If you need something more or examples, just tell me it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please fix the types? There isn't a single thing in that Array that remotely resembles a string but you are declaring it as `Array[(String, String)]` and then later you are mapping `x(0)` to String, which would be redundant if it actually contained a string. And what does this condition mean `BD_classified -> users` ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have to check if the first string contains one of that options. For example, if the string 0 of the array contains "BD_classified" I have to return "users". I am new with the RDD's for that reason I don't know how exactly works :(

Comment: when you `map` and RDD the function you pass into `map` is applied to every single function. All you have to do is write a function with `if` statements that checks for the substrings you want and return the correct thing for every branch. There are various ways to check if a String contains a substring. You can use `regex` or use one of the functions defined on Strings

Comment: Thank you @sinanspd and what would be more efficient for Apache Spark, use if else with a flag to get out of the bucle when i find a solution or better use case?

Comment: Doesn't matter. It is highly unlikely that you will ever have enough data to notice the difference. Don't micromanage your code

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming you have a RDD of strings and a classifier already defined:

```scala
  val rdd: RDD[String] =
    ???

  def classify(input: String): String =
    ???
  
  rdd.map(input => classify(input))
```